# readAsDataURL returns an invalid Base64 string for PNG, but not for JPG/JPEG

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Running a React Native app, and trying to solve this issue.
The b64 is sent to a an API and stored in db as blob, I know it's not best practice, but this isn't an app of any scale, just a simple student project.

```
const file = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        type: "image/*",
        copyToCacheDirectory: true,
    });
```

for mobile:

```
const uri = await fetch(file.uri);
const blob = await uri.blob();
const res = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
}).then((result) => {
   return result;
}); 
base64 = res as string;
```

for web i just use file.uri since it's b64 there.

However, in both cases b64 for the png is incorrect, but it's correct for jpg and jpeg. Is this a known issue, or have I just missed some special guards I need to take for the alpha value?

FYI running react-native using expo

Edit, example of the b64 this produces for png:

```
https://controlc.com/f9073658 -b64 too long for SO
```

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is just encoding bytes using 64 ASCII symbols. I am not sure I got what is wrong with PNG but if you want you can use standard Image component from React Native like this:

```
// include at least width and height!
<Image
  style={{
    width: 51,
    height: 51,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }}
  source={{
    uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Yeah, the data that is returned from the API/DB is the same b64 which is inserted in the source as URI. This works fine for JPG/JPEG currently.
The PNG Base64 is incorrect, but JPG/JPEG is correct, by using the method in my post.

Comment: what is an error for PNG? can you share a screenshot? Can you try this component https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image

Comment: to be clear, the issue isn't in loading the images. it's that the PNG -> b64 process above creates invalid B64, pasting the URI into chrome renders errors. Added sample b64 to the question to clarify

Comment: @groeterud problem in your string, I tried it and I can't render it in the browser. You need to find where you loose data.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem - I don't know enough about b64 to know where to begin debugging that.

Comment: Take your image and use a service like this https://www.base64-image.de convert to base64 and compare it with your string.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. In my case, the problem was that the base64 engine that I was using in the backend was padless, so any base64 strign with the padding character (`=`) resulted in a decoding error.

Of course the solution was to change the base64 engine to one that included the padding.